# Is Tomcat 7.0.10 Java EE 6 Compliant? javax.inject woes

Tags: spring, java-ee-6, tomcat7

Folks- I'm following an example from Craig Walls' "Spring in Action 3" (MEAP edition) on Tomcat 7.0.10. Getting a compiler error in eclipse on the following import:

`import javax.inject.Inject;`

The error message is:

`The import javax.inject cannot be resolved`

I understand javax.inject is part of Java EE 6, is Tomcat 7 not Java EE 6 compliant? I have all the jars in $CATALINA/lib copied to my WEB-INF/lib directory, also did a manual search (jar -tvf) but couldn't find this package.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: i suppose you are confusing the injection mechanisms provided by spring with those of java EE. As axtavt said, vanilla tomcat does not support EE. You do not need any jars except the ones provided by spring

Comment: You mean the spring-3 jars provided by spring should have JSR-330 implementation included? Thx.

Comment: Not really. To my knowledge, spring does not implement the jsr330 and does not intend to (and does not need to). The jsr concerns only java EE. The container ( or context) spring uses for dependeny injection is different from a container that say JBoss uses. I guess what misled you was eclipse's "organize dependencies" function which sometimes makes bad guesses about your intentions.

Comment: @Kevin: Spring supports JSR-330, but it's optional, so that JSR-330 jar is not provided with Spring.

Comment: Besides, you dont even need a server at all to enjoy spring's DI goodness.There is a nice (and short and simple) tutorial at [vogella tutorials](http://www.vogella.de/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html). It's easy to get confused in the beginning, so start small.

Comment: @axtavt: i wasnt aware of that. thanks for pointing it out. I supposed the problem was of a rather conceptual nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat is a servlet container, therefore it has nothing to do with JSR-330  (`javax.inject`).

If you want to use JSR-330 annotations, you need to add [JSR-330 jar](http://code.google.com/p/atinject/downloads/detail?name=javax.inject.zip) to the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Maven, you can use the following pom.xml and it will automatically download the Spring and Java EE jars for your project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.acmeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringInjectDemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is just a Servlet container and is not Java EE 6 compliant. You can use GlassFish 3.1 (glassfish.org) which is a fully Java EE 6-compliant app server with clustering and high availability.